# Enumerate: How to make one instance of ref be non-hyperlinked?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

In a document I have an `enumerate` environment with labels. I usually use `ref` to reference one item, but in a specific (rare but not unique) place I would like the refence to *not* be a hyperref. I could "hardcode" the name of the item, but it's ugly and if I ever change my numeration system, I'll have to proof-read everything. Is there any way to make one instance of `ref` not a hyperref ?

To be clear, my goal is having something looking as follow (the first (P1) is clickable, the second not):

[image]

So far I am "hardcoding" it, but I would like to use a fully automatic solution (something like `\nonhyperref{item:prop1}`) instead.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
List of properties :
\begin{enumerate}[label=(P\arabic*)]
    \item property 1 \label{item:prop1}
    \item property 2 \label{item:prop2}
\end{enumerate}


Later we prove property \ref{item:prop1} of $X$ by using property (P1) of $Y$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\ref*`. The `hyperref` manual says on the bottom of p. 20
[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
List of properties :
\begin{enumerate}[label=(P\arabic*)]
    \item property 1 \label{item:prop1}
    \item property 2 \label{item:prop2}
\end{enumerate}


Later we prove property \ref{item:prop1} of $X$ by using property \ref*{item:prop1} of $Y$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that if you load `enumitem` it makes sense to avoid also loading `enumerate`.